# Can angular-cdk's datasource be used with an md-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm using Angular 4 and the current beta version of [Angular Material 2 (2.0.0-beta8)](https://github.com/angular/material2).

Material's table component is built on top of the CDK data-table. As such, it's very easy to hook up a backend that will call out to services/apis for data, and it implements all of the hookups for using RxJS Observables to things. (See the [demo here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).)

What I'm trying to figure out is if I can use the same `DataSource` interface out of @angular/cdk and use it to populate a bunch of `md-select` elements.

Eg something like this:

```html
<md-select class="col-lg-4" placeholder="Product" [dataSource]="configData">
  <md-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id">{{product.display_name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

This doesn't work because `md-select` doesn't have a `dataSource` property. Is there a similar interface or property I can use on the `md-select`? What I'm trying to do is not have to re-implement all of the Observables and other reactive functionality being used by the md-table/dataSource implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install @matheo/datasource
```

I released a library aimed to be the official Material DataSource in the future, supporting any kind of input streams (sort, pagination, filters), and some configuration with debugging to see how it works while you're coding.

```
import { MatDataSourceModule } from '@matheo/datasource';
```

Your selects can be part of a form, triggering changes and refreshing the `DataSource` with the REQuest built from the values of your selectors.

You can find the StackBlitz demo and further information here:
https://medium.com/@matheo/reactive-datasource-for-angular-1d869b0155f6

I'd be glad to hear your opinion and support your use cases if necessary.
Happy coding!